# Customizing Cocoas NSFontPanel

Tags: cocoa, macos, fonts, panel, nsfontpanel

What customization options are there for Cocoas NSFontPanel?

The NSFontPanel accessible in iWork Pages has "Text Underline", "Text Strikethrough" and "Document Color" controls at the top. We don't want these in our NSFontPanel. Is there any way to remove or disable these controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement [the NSFontPanelValidation protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSFontPanelValidation_Protocol/) in the relevant responder(s).

Comment: Nice, I've never seen that one.

Comment: Sweet - just what I've needed!

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, the responder must implement the NSFontPanelValidation protocol and override the - (NSUInteger)validModesForFontPanel:(NSFontPanel *)fontPanel method. But this method does not invoked when the NSFontPanel showed.